# Cheap waterproof IP67+ connectors with 6 pins

Tags: connector, waterproof

I'm designing some instruments for cash strapped conservation projects. Usually I tend towards the expensive IP68 circular connectors but trying to minimise cost where possible.

I'm going panel box to cable with data and a 5w power - any good suggestions?

I need at least 6 pins and it needs to be disconnected by not that disciplined users. The devices are sitting in the jungle above water but with a lot of rain.

Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest this self-latching one with button release:

- MANUF. - SERIES
- [Souriau](https://www.souriau.com/en-en/products/connectors/circular-connectors/utl-series) - [UTL-10 (hybrid)](https://ipaper.ipapercms.dk/SOURIAU/UTLSeriesEurope/) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/h71rwwhd)

[image: Souriau UTL-10]

{Souriau}

**EDIT**: DANG! Why the down vote?

Comment: The thread got flagged and closed for asking for product recommendations as it's not useful to people... It's useful to me and thank you for taking the time to reply.